# Wouldn't Maxwell's demon violate the first law of thermodynamics and if so, is Landauer's principle even needed in this case?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

If Maxwell's demon were able to separate a gas into hot and cold regions without adding energy to the system, we would be able to move a piston between the two chambers until the temperatures equalize again thus creating work out of nothing. This however violates the first law of thermodynamics, therefore Maxwell's demon is impossible. **Isn't this enough evidence to reject Maxwell's demon outright?**

Landauer's principle is a much weaker argument against Maxwell's demon, so why is it the preferred solution to Maxwell's demon instead of first law violation?

Comment: Please explain in more detail the process described as: "we would be able to move a piston between the two chambers until the temperatures equalize again thus creating work out of nothing"

Comment: As individual gas molecules approach the door, the demon quickly opens and shuts the door so that only fast molecules are passed into one of the chambers, while only slow molecules are passed into the other. Because faster molecules are hotter, **the demon's behaviour causes one chamber to warm up and the other to cool down**, thereby decreasing entropy and violating the second law of thermodynamics. And if the wall between the chambers is unlocked, it will moves like a piston in an internal combustion engine, thus generating free work.

Comment: How does this violate the First Law, as written in your question? The piston movement would remove the same amount of energy from the gas.

Comment: The hypothesis is that the demon doesn't add any energy to the system when opening and closing the door, yet we get energy out via the piston. And repeatedly, if the demon so chooses, thus making a perpetual motion machine of the first kind. This can't happen due to the laws of thermodynamics, hence the demon hypothesis fails. And Landauer's principle adds nothing to this conclusion.

Comment: Your misunderstanding is that a heat engine creates energy in the form of work. If a pressure difference between between two gases moves a slider, the work transferred corresponds to an energy reduction in the gases.

Comment: No, there is no energy reduction since the the final state is exactly as the initial state, namely a homogeneous gas. Remember: INITIAL = homogeneous gas + energy neutral demon while FINAL = homogeneous gas + work + energy neutral demon. The difference between initial and final is work that came out of nowhere. This clearly violates the first law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Saying it over and over doesn't make it so. I don't disagree that a heat engine can be run between two chambers of gas until their pressures and temperature are equal, but I do disagree that their temperatures would be the same as if you just connected them without the engine. The energy in the form of work has to come from somewhere. I analyze this scenario [here](http://john.maloney.org/square_root.htm).

Comment: OK, so obviously a heat engine is needed to extract the work. No problem. Next, perhaps I missed something: are you saying that once work is extracted, the homogeneous system temperature will be different that the original homogeneous system temperature? Will it decrease (I think)? If so, then the next cycle has a different starting point, but the demon can still separate the particles by speed thus recreating the conditions for more work extraction. Is this not violating the first principle?

Comment: IOW, say the starting point is 25 deg C. The demon separates into 1/2 at 0 deg C and 1/2 at 50 deg C. We extract work, thus homogenizing the two sides. Will this new temperature now be lower than 25 deg C?

Comment: Yes, in this thought experiment, the temperature of the gas continues to decrease as you extract work from it. No, this doesn't violate the First Law, as energy would stay conserved, but it does violate the Second Law, as entropy would be destroyed. Yes, the temperature in the case you describe would be <25°C.

Comment: This is great clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are various versions of the Maxwell's demon scenario, but generally they are deliberately posed in a way not to violate the first law.  As presented in much of the popular literature, the demon (explicitly or implicitly) allows the same number of particles to go in each direction.  That means the internal energy on one side increases while on the other side it decreases.  That means the demon generates a pressure difference between the two chambers, which can then be used to drive a piston and do external work as you describe.  The work comes from the original internal energy of the system, though, so the system loses energy to the surround as the work is done.  To restore the system to its original state, you would need to dissipate that external work back into heating the system.  In this case the apparent violation of the 2nd law is that the demon generates a pressure-separated state, which is lower-entropy than the initial state, without (apparently) doing any work.

In a version of the demon that's a little closer to the original, the demon moves more low-energy particles than high-energy, so as to keep the internal energy the same on both sides.  The high-energy side ends up with fewer particles and a higher temperature, the lower side has more particles and a lower temperature, but the pressures (proportional to the internal energy) are equal.  That's more subtle, because now you can't extract work just by driving a piston with a pressure difference.  You can, however, drive a heat engine, which can produce work as it transmits heat from the high-T side to the low-T side.  However, the work still comes from the internal energy of the system, so there is no violation of the first law.  In fact, now the violation of the 2nd law is not so obvious - since there is equal energy going into and out of each side, it would seem that any increase in entropy due to heat flow into a chamber would be compensated by a decrease due to heat flow out.  It turns out, though, that the net particle flux is associated with an increase in entropy of the low-T side and a decrease on the high-T side, and that the decrease outweighs the increase, so the sorting is in fact connected with lowering the entropy of the system.